# implement default class instance method

Tags: python

i have the following class which i use when declaring 'constants' to map one value to another.  Is there away in python implement a default method such that anytime an instance of this class referenced without a specific method, a default method is executed?

```
class FieldMap:
    def __init__(self, old_field, new_field):
        self._fld_map = (old_field, new_field)

    def old_fld(self):
        return self._fld_map[0]

    def new_fld(self):
        return self._fld_map[1]

SEC_ID = FieldMap('value','price')
SEC_NAME = FieldMap('entity_name', 'security_name')
SEC_TICKER = FieldMap('entity_attr', 'ticker')

#Edit: updating example to provide a real example of what i want to achieve
dict = {}
dict['price'] = 1234
print dict[SEC_ID]  <--would like this to print out the value 1234 because ideally, the default method would call new_fld() and return 'price'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to implement an automatic method call in all cases, but it is possible to hook into certain method calls. In the case of `print`, Python will attempt to call a `__str__` method on the instance if one exists. So you could do something like this:

```
class FieldMap:
    def __init__(self, old_field, new_field):
        self._fld_map = (old_field, new_field)

    def old_fld(self):
        return self._fld_map[0]

    def new_fld(self):
        return self._fld_map[1]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.new_fld()
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't call a default method, but it sounds like you just want to override `__str__`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self._fld_map[1]
```

Note that this is just the definition of `new_fld`, so you could simply add the following to your class:

```
__str__ = new_fld
```

Comment: thanks, that works for print. it doesn't work for say something like this though mydict[SEC_ID] = 1234.   i know that isn't exactly what i asked, maybe i will update the question

Comment: In that case, you need to either call `str(SEC_ID)` or store elements using `dict[SEC_ID] = 1234` and then `dict[SEC_ID]` to retrieve. In general, you can't expect Python to magically convert types-- how would it know to convert to string or integer in most cases?